# Integral for Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

1. Find $\int_{\gamma} 1/z^3 \,dz$ where $\gamma$ is the semi-circle $|z − 1| = 2$, Im$(z) \geq 0$
2. Find $\int_{\gamma} e^z \, dz   $ where $\gamma$ is the semi-circle $|z| = 1,$ Im$(z) \leq 0$;

How should I approach these problem?

My approach:
For question 2, I know that the integral of $e^z$ is $e^z$, but I need to use two ways: using Cauchy’s theorem and deforming the contour and by finding anti-derivatives of the integrand to find the solution under the given condition. How do I do this in two different ways?

Also I don't understand about the semi-circle radius.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is for closed paths. That's not the case here.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, that is what I thought as well, but the question tells me to solve it using two ways and how both results are the same for each integral.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, can you help me on solving one of them, just wanted to see how to solve using two ways. thanks!

Comment: Plus, I am not sure how to handle the question for the semi-circle, I know if it is just a full circle with radius.

Comment: So, it was just a matter of doing it in two different ways? It is *not* required to use Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, yes. I am also having a difficulty understanding the given gamma condition. Does semi-circle mean going from 0 to pi? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like you need to be given the orientation (or parameterization) of $\gamma$.

Comment: @saulspatz you mean using e^it form and just use the f(γ(t))γ'(t) formula for integral?

Comment: I just mean that it's an oriented integral. If you switch the orientation, then you negate the value of the integral.  $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$.  So, it seems like we have to be told the orientation of $\gamma$.

Comment: wait, why do we use the negation and change the direction? is it possible to explain?

Comment: For the amti-derivative approach at least it looks like you need to parametrize the path $\gamma$, and that you'll need to split it into two integrals because you have a line segment then half the circle, both making one path. To get you started, you can parametrize a circle using $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. A line segment between $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ could be parametrized using $z=a+t(b-a)$ where $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @metamorphy, thanks for your reply, You mean using F(b) - F(a) from the fundamental theorem of Calculus? Can you elaborate how to do such in semi-circle? thanks in advance

Comment: @mathrock1453: Just take $a$ to be the starting point (where your semicircle begins) and $b$ the final point (where it ends). It *must* be specified what the direction is.

Comment: so in this case, for q1, from 3 to -1, or in term of theta, from 0 to pi?